# CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes is deprecated. Replacement?

Tags: objective-c, gdata, cfurl-encoding

Here is my code

```
CFStringRef escapedStr;

  escapedStr = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                       originalString,
                                                       leaveUnescaped,
                                                       kCharsToForceEscape,
                                                       kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

The Error is:

> CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes is deprecated in ios 9.0, use
>   stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters which always uses
>   recommended UTF-8 settings.

Could somebody help with how to replace `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` with `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` in above code.

Comment: Why would you ask a question that you know is a duplicate? Anyway, it's almost always nonsensical to want to percent-encode entire strings. Read (Apple's release notes discussion)[https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/#10_11URL] about this subject.

Answer (score -1):

use below code maybe its helped

```
CFStringRef escapedStr;
escapedStr = (__bridge CFStringRef)([str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[kCFAllocatorDefault,originalString,leaveUnescaped,kCharsToForceEscape,kCFStringEncodingUTF8]]);// here str is your NSString
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I am getting these 2 new errors after putting above code

1.Expression Result unusual
2.Expected Identifier